# Too many dotnet processes with high memory use

Tags: performance, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, amazon-lightsail

I have just deployed an app to ubuntu server (aws - lightsail). When the app runs its creating multiple dotnet processes with high virtual memory. The app becomes really slow. Not inresponsive but really slow. You can notice multiple dotnet processes from screenshot.

dotnet core 5
aspnet boilerplate application
AWS lightsail instance (linux)

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Green ones are threads, not process. You can press <kbd>F1</kbd> to configure their appearance. High virtual memory usage is also ok, it's not real RAM used.